# Desplegar módulos cdk en aws y python

Tags: python, aws

Necesito ayuda para desplegar un módulo de Ec2 en Python a través de cdk  no soy capaz de hacer un synt, ni un bootstrap y me estoy desesperando ¿podrían ayudarme?